# synonymize [google-python-api] and [google-api-python-client]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

Tag excerpt for [google-python-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-python-api):

> The Google API Client Library for Python is designed for Python client-application developers. It offers simple, flexible access to many Google APIs.
>   https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/

[google-api-python-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-python-client):

> The Google APIs Client Library for Python provides access to for Google's discovery based APIs. It is designed for Python client-application developers and offers simple, flexible, powerful API access.

According to the excerpts they both deal with the same api.

The latter is sponsored by Google. So, can [google-python-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-python-api) be synonymized with  [google-api-python-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-python-client) as the main tag?